# Bootstrap classes to Django UpdateView

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

Built-in UpdateView View class create form in my app, but I want add to form Bootstrap class in my HTML, how can i do it?

```
 class ProfileUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Profile
    fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'patronymic', 'profile_picture', 'bio']
    template_name = 'profiles/profile_form.html'
    success_url = ''
```

Comment: you can use the django messages framework to css in html from view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add class with [django-widget-tweaks](https://pypi.org/project/django-widget-tweaks/), but you can't add class directly to form you should use the filter render_field for customizing fields of form.

**In your settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
...
'widget_tweaks',
...
]
```

**In your template you can put like this**

```
{% load widget_tweaks %} 

<form>
{% csrf_token %}
{% for field in form %}

  {% if field.errors %}

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="id_{{ field.name }}">{{ field.label }}:</label>
    {% render_field field class="form-control is-invalid" %}
    <div class="invalid-feedback">
      <ul>
        {% for error in field.errors %}
          <li>{{error|escape}}</li>
        {% endfor %}
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  {% else %}
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="id_{{ field.name }}">{{ field.label }}:</label>
      {% render_field field class="form-control" %}
    </div>
  {% endif %}


{% endfor %}

</form>
```

Another easier way is to use [django-crispy-forms](https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html), which adds bootstrap styles more automatically.

**In your settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
...
'crispy_forms',
)
```

**You can render the entire form**

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %} 
{% my_form|crispy %}
```

**Or a field**

```
    {% load crispy_forms_tags %}
    {{my_form.field|as_crispy_field}}
```

If you simply want to add a class to the form you can do this:

```
<form class="my_bootstrap_class">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form %}
        ...
    {% endfor %}

</form>
```